# Why are null bytes not working?

Tags: php, null, byte

I have created a simple website based on my knowledge but I discovered that it suffers from a Local File Inclusion (**LFI**) vulnerability. I want to test exploiting it on my computer but whenever I try to bypass with null bytes that doesn't work. I wrote this simple code and tried it, but it is still not working => [test.php?page=index.php%00 (to show index.php in current dir)]

```
$page=$_GET['page'];
if(!include($page.".php"))
phpinfo();
```

Can anyone suggest a solution to get it done?
(`../../etc/passwd` also not working )

I am using **PHP 5.3.2** and **Apache 2.2.14** and **firefox**.

Comment: please use full words and complete sentences. This isn't twitter and you are not paying by the letter to post or anything.

Comment: To get *what* done exactly?

Answer (score 2):

`include` is not a boolean function.

Try

```
if( file_exists($_GET['page'] . ".php") ) {
    include($_GET['page'] . ".php");
}
```

You would then call `scriptName.php?page=test` to see if `test.php` exists.

Comment: well if func worked with include as bool

Comment: Include behaves a bit like a function, but is a control structure. Look here for checking the "return" value of it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 0):

I always use a whitelist, so allowed pages. If 'index' is not within the allowed pages, I don't inlude it. [assumed: ?page=index and $allowed = ARRAY('index', 'home', 'imprint', ...)]

Comment: but what i really want is why i can't bypass it with null bytes so if i give it value &page=index.php%00 ,it'll show dat page.
char buf[INT]={'x1',x2',x3','\0','x3'};
cout <<buf;
output will be => x1x2x3
so normally include will be as so 
include($page);
can u explain ??

Comment: I know. ("Never trust user input" is anyway the best solution. So if applicable, I use this way...)

Answer (score 0):

PHP =/= C. PHP handles NUL bytes in strings with no problems.

Also take care that %00 is not filtered on the server level.

[See how it works](http://codepad.viper-7.com/9jqq29/55dev?a=1%002).

Comment: Nop 
even magic_qoutes_gpc=OFF
im working on my localhost

Comment: Nop what? See the link, no problem to have NUL bytes in PHP. Does not cut-off any strings.